Quarkus: Tenant Swagger UI
I defined a rest endpoint with multiple tenant
@RequestScoped
@Path("/api/v1/calendar/{tenant}")
public class CalendarEndpoint {

    @Inject
    CalendarRepository repository;

    @POST
    @Path("appointments")
    @PermitAll
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Operation(summary = "Termine laden", description = "Lädt für einen bestimmten Zeitraum die Termine")
    @APIResponses(value = {
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Termine erfolgreich geladen", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ArrayList.class))),
            @APIResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "Authentifizierung nicht erfolgreich", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ExceptionHandler.ErrorResponseBody.class))) })
    public List<RWeek> getAppointments(RAppointmentDates dates) {
        return repository.findByDateRange(dates);
    }

}

How I can define the "tenant" Parameter in the Swagger UI? This parameter is not visible.
Swagger UI
A @PathParameter on the method definition has no effect.
